# How to generate report (graph) in PHP

Tags: php, dreamweaver

a friend of mine is using Dreamweaver and PHP to develop a system for her final year project.

her system should be able to generate report that includes graph generation.

Could anyone suggest any way to do this or any tutorial/tools that is easy to use as she is a newbie to PHP.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I suggest checking out http://pchart.sourceforge.net/ or the Google Charts API and Image Charts API, http://code.google.com/apis/chart/ and http://code.google.com/apis/chart/image/

Answer (score 3):

Do you mean [graphs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_%28mathematics%29) or [charts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chart)?

While there's lots of stuff available I'd recommend [graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org/) for the former and [jpgraph](http://jpgraph.net/) or [Google charts](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/) for the latter.

Comment: i will ask her to try these.TQ